# How to protect .env file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I moved my project to HOST but I can still access .env with address mysite.com/.env and display this file with all variables and secure data.
my .env file :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:xxxxxxx
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xx
DB_USERNAME=xx
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

How I can protect this file? And this is the logical solution?

note : (I move all files public folder in root directory.)

Comment: Apache denys access to files which start with `.` by default. What webserver are you using?

Comment: My webserver is Apache.

Comment: .env is supposed to be in /path/to/your/laravel-project. And /path/to/your/laravel-project/public should be the webroot. So unless you changed the default setup you should not be able to access the .env

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/47355544/6517383 this answer uses file permissions

Comment: Check this post: [How to secure Laravel .env file and file permission?](https://devnote.in/how-to-secure-the-env-file-in-laravel-using-file-permission/)

Answer (score 27):

Create .htaccess file in your Root Directory and put following Code.

```
#Disable index view
options -Indexes

#hide a Specifuc File

<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: thats the fastest and best way to do it

Comment: I found that not only .env file but also all files of laravel are in the same situation. What is the best way to protect all laravel files (except the public folder). Do we need to set permission 600 for all files?

Comment: @Nguyen Duc Linh [Solution via Permission](https://devnote.in/how-to-secure-the-env-file-in-laravel-using-file-permission/)

Comment: It is a good approach for .env file, but how to protect other? Like composer.json and package.json? Do we need to do it all one by one?

Answer (score 8):

I have tried the following steps to deploy Laravel in the shared hosting.

1 - Edit the **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** in Ubuntu OS.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All # Changed from None to All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2. Enable mod rewrite `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
3. Edit or create .htaccess in the root (Public HTML folder)

   ```
    <Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|xml|gitignore|gitattributes|lock|editorconfig|yml|styleci.yml)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
    Options -Indexes
    <Files ~ "(artisan|package.json|webpack.mix.js)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
   ```

4 - Restart Apache server, `sudo service apache2 restart`

> Note:- First two steps are used only on my own PC.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for how to stop .env files from being served on apache hence read.

do this on the /etc/apache2/apache.conf file - Ubuntu. after this part of that file
`<FilesMatch "^\.ht">`
 `Require all denied`
`</FilesMatch>`

add the code below

```
# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

then restart your apache server with `sudo service apache2 restart` and enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

1. All except the Public folder to move to a higher level, such as a folder laravel - http://prntscr.com/bryvu7
2. Change file publi_html/index.php
   line

   `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

And line

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

3. Change file laravel/server.php
   line

   `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';`

to

```
require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
```

Comment: Thanks.But after do these things,when go to mysite.com display laravel folder and public folder do not display index website.

Comment: Maybe on hosting your folder - public. not a folder public_html?

Answer (score 1):

You should change permission all folder on your app to 741, except bootstrap and storage and public (755).

Answer (score 0):

In my case when was I host my project in shared hosting my .env file was accessible, my folder structure was like this
Root
|+   App
|       App
|       config
|       Database
|       Routes
|       Storage
|       .env
|       ...
|     index.php
|    .htaccess
|+    css
|+    js

My .env file was accessible via this website.com/app/.env
**Solution**
Put all your public content to a folder name it public and change the root document path in settings [don't forget to change app.php path in index.php file]
|+app
|+public

bootrap.php file path should be like this /../app/vendor/autload.php & /../app/bootstrap/app.php

Answer (score 0):

move`.htaccess` from public folder and then you have paste this code in `.htaccess` file.

`<Files .env> Order allow,deny Deny from all </Files>`