# Why my configuration files are getting accessed from browser in laravel?

Tags: laravel, security

I have hosted my project on the server and my application is getting hacked, as of now I came to know my configuration files are no secured like .env, composer.json etc. These can be directly accessed by saying mydomain/filname e.g., www.abc.com/.env, when anybody hits url like this then file is opened on the browser. How can protect these files. I am using lravel 5.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How protect .env file laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331397/how-protect-env-file-laravel)

Comment: if you use apache server then redirect all request to index.php file and only allow access to js,css and fonts file by using .htaccess file

Comment: As [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8#configuration), you should configure your web server document root to point to the `public/` directory.  That way your `.env` and other code is not accessible.  It sounds like currently your document root is actually your project root, which means **everything** is exposed.

Comment: BTW once you fix the problem you should change all sensitive details, passwords, keys, etc, as they've all been exposed and potentially accessed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have multiple .htaccess files and your server isn't using the one that Laravel provides.